# Mysql update data multiple times with inner join data

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join

I have two tables. One is "**new_content**" that i want to update. Second is "**files**". I want to update new_content table content column, adding files related to ids.

files table:

```
    new_content_id   |   filename
    -------------------------
    1            |   file1
    1            |   file2
    3            |   file3
    3            |   file4
    5            |   file5
```

new_content table:

```
    id           |   content
    ----------------------------
    1            |   text1
    2            |   
    3            |   text2
    4            |   text3
    5            |   text4
```

I want new_content table to be:

```
    id           |   content
    ----------------------------
    1            |   text1 file1 file2
    2            |   text2
    3            |   file3 file4
    4            |   text3
    5            |   text4 file5
```

I wrote this code:

```
    UPDATE `new_content` n
    INNER JOIN files f
    ON n.id = f.subpage_id
    SET n.content = concat(n.content,'<br>br>',f.filename);
```

it only updates one row from files, for each content.

result:

```
    id           |   content
    ----------------------------
    1            |   text1 file1
    2            |   text2
    3            |   file3
    4            |   text3
    5            |   text4 file5
```

can anyone help?

**edit:**

Related to answers i couldn't update directly but i could write a select query and solved question. Thanks.

```
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT f.filename
    ORDER BY f.filename) FROM`new_content` n
    INNER JOIN files f
    ON n.id = f.subpage_id
    GROUP BY f.subpage_id
    ORDER BY f.subpage_id;
```

Comment: Why not,a stored procedure with temporary table because you can achieve this easily with `GROUP_CONCAT()`. Or maybe a MERGE with a `GROUP_CONCAT()` subquery.

Comment: Even ignoring files entirely, I don't understand the relationship between the data set and the result set.

Comment: I can combine tables with select but when i try to update "content" column, only one filename from "files" is added. If there are multiple files for one id i cant get them.

Comment: Thanks for quick return.